# Google Cloud HTTPS Loadbalancer routing not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have tree Cloud Run testing services: hello-default, hello-blue, hello-green.

I've created an HTTPs Loadbalancer having those 3 services as individual backend services as Network Endpoint Groups. That means the Loadbalancer has 3 backend services, one for each mentioned service.

I want to achieve this basic routing:
[image]

My goal is to send "hello.site.com/blue/" to be sent to `hello-blue` service and "hello.site.com/green/" to be sent to `hello-green`

But when I save the Loadbalancer the routing table changes to this:
[image]

And when I go to "hello.site.com/blue/" and "hello.site.com/green/" they always hit the hello-default backend, which gives 404 because it doesn't have those paths.

Then, I edited my Loadbalancer to set the routing as the following with no success:
[image]

It seems the routing is being completely ignored. What have I missed? Why does GCP adds those extra routing rules "/*"

Comment: Shouldn't "hosts" be set to hello.site.com or it won't match anything?

Comment: Facepalm. You are absolutelly right. Thank you. It's working now?

Comment: @Mauricio From the above comment, I believe that your issue is solved. Can you post your answer as a solution? So that, it will be useful for others who are facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

As @Joachim Isaksson pointed out, it turns out I missed the meaning of the "Hosts" field on the routing setting. Using the right host value fixed the issue.
[image]